# PHP GD live edit image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, gd

I have a form where I POST some variables to make an image (text, padding, background image and text position)

```
<form id="form" action="img.php" method="post" name="form">
<label>text</label> <textarea name="text"></textarea>
<label>Author</label> <input name="author"></input>
<label>text padding</label> <input type="number" name="padding" min="10" max="200" value="30">
text-align:
<input type="radio" name="align" value="1"> left
<input type="radio" name="align" value="0" checked="yes"> center
<input type="radio" name="align" value="2"> right
<select name="background">
<option>- select image -</option>
<?php $range = range(0, 177);
foreach ($range as $key) { ?>
<option id="img" value="src/img<?php echo $key;?>.jpg">src/img<?php echo $key;?>.jpg</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

The script works very well when I send those variables to the img.php file. I wanted to do a live modification on the same page, like an image editor with ajax, but when I run this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // loader
        $().ajaxStart(function(){
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#result').hide();
        }).ajaxStop(function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        // post submit values
        $('#form').submit(function(){
            // ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            })
            return false;
        });

    })

</script>
```

This error comes up on the html file and I can't get the image:

```
����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality ��C     $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"��   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��'*���d^�~��N�7��dWF�E�����F�E!�8�QrG��H=y�+V�R�ei�ֳK����tX8����<����(R�ϥHaR�s �a��p���y�QbTe��_)�1���qW^�&� �73}��l�Ƴ��.`�E�-�-'#a�*ݏ�Zvךm��g^���&���ڄ�0"�tE��R]:I���U�\u�oǊ��o�a:T�%gF���s�?�*�Y���W�-�YL`���p2O_z�n��#�=:���l���T[��<�Y�6�̲/Ƹ�Ye�7����%W#��@���խm��d�s��o_�qQ�Ln���nC��'�ןҁ���/�� �������t�ޞ9N6�e��Ю?�dxN��Y�P+Ӧ��*�w���/���l�|�����?Z��6�q/�#c����d���Ȫ�͙N"/*�V���#4�������(1:��YF$�n=*��D H8ɦ%��R�I����AP~��օs������g �;FB���T� ��S��7kB�L�M�Gǿ4��_Ean��� ��S\����ߝ"<��U8>�ڬ"�+8�y��va�?Z��9�m��sO�wo���N    �HE���%eDY  ,�... and goes on...
```

How can I get the image with ajax?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The img.php works fine when I submit those variables to the img.php window on the browser but its kinda extense to post it here, this is a sample:

img.php

```
<?php 
require_once("functions.php");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

// Settings
$fontSize = 28;
$font = "./fonts/Oswald-Medium.ttf";
$fontlogo = "./fonts/Quicksand-Bold.otf";

$background = $_POST['background'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$padding = $_POST['padding']; //from edges
$align = $_POST['align'];

.
.
etc
.
.

$md = md5($background).".jpg";
imagejpeg($im, './images/'.$md);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The problem it's on the ajax script to make a live edit of those variables and generate de image on the same window.

Comment: you need to show your `php` code as well

Comment: @cmorrissey the php code it's kinda extense to post it here and works fine when i get the information on the img.php window, the problem it's on the ajax script to load

Comment: there are 2 answers for this so here's my question to determine what one you want.  Do you want to actually save these user generated images to your server?

Comment: @cmorrissey sure, it saves the last modification of the image on the script img.php, thats why im trying to do the edit thing in live time to be sure that would be the version I want to save :) sorry my bad english hehe

Answer (score 0):

`img.php` is returning a JPEG file:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
...
imagejpeg($im, './images/'.$md);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Accessing `img.php` directly works because your browser is told (via the header) to expect a JPEG file and renders the data it receives as such.

When accessing `img.php` via AJAX you tell the browser to treat the output as text, and that's what it does:

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

Since you're saving the image to the server you should only return the path to the image (not the image itself) when calling via AJAX. Then you can just tell the browser to add an `img` element with the image path:

```
$('#result').append($('<img>').attr('src', image_url));
```

Comment: thanks, i'm new using ajax and js, the image_url must be on a variable and the data is taken from an input like image_name, right? ex. var image_url = '/images/' + $('#image_name').val();